# django getlist() from ajax html form

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

Im trying to send my serialized form data to django where it will should be stored in "mylist" as a list "[video, audio]". views.py return 0 everytime no matter what boxes I check on my form.

html form

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="audio"/> Audio<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="video"/> Video<br />
<input type="submit" value="Get Custom Library!" /> 
</form>
```

jquery ajax

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myform").submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'django/builder/buildit',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def main(request):
  mylist = request.POST.getlist('list')
  message = 0
  for item in mylist:
    if item == 'video':
      message = 'vid'
    elif item == 'audio':
      message = 'aud'
  return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: `data: { list: myCheckboxes },`

Comment: Try inserting `print(item)` in views.py to find out its actual value?

Comment: Why don't you use `if 'video' in mylist` instead of for loop?

Comment: I changed my views.py and removed my `for` loop. I am getting a internal server error on my views page now which means "mylist" is not a list. Why isnt my serialized data being added as a list to "mylist"?

Comment: print POST variables and see their structure you can `print request.POST` in view or drop in a debugger so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving a key value pair to the `data` argument, but you shouldn't even have to go that far - you don't have to gather the checkbox values yourself. You can replace this:

```
    var myCheckboxes = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'django/builder/buildit',
        data: myCheckboxes,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

With this, using [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'django/builder/buildit',
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How would I store the serialized data in the "mylist" variable as a list in django that looks like this [video, audio]

Comment: @user1442957 What you have in your view should work with the above code.

Comment: I edited my main post and now views.py just keeps returning '0' no matter what is checked. I dont think my data is getting stored in "mylist" as a list.

Comment: 1. Please don't edit your question in response to an answer to change what's being asked. 2. What happens when you log/print the contents of `mylist` within your view?

Comment: I have debugging enabled but how do I print or log the value of a variable?